# Powershell command returns null on success

Tags: powershell

I am writing small utility scripts in Powershell. While trying to follow the principle of doing one job extremely well per script, I am running into an issue with one script that returns a null value on success. When I try to run the command, and pipe it through a command such as `Send-MailMessage`, I get an error when it should be successful. I am trying to get `Send-MailMessage` to only fire if there is output in the body (otherwise, there would be many emails coming in).

Currently, I'm trying to run this from the Powershell command line:

`Send-MailMessage -From "powershell@example.com" -To "tech@example.com" -Subject "Disk usage on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)" -SmtpServer "192.168.0.1" -Body (.\diskUsage.ps1 | Out-String) -ErrorAction Continue`

The error I'm receiving:

`Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:156
+ ... SmtpServer "192.168.0.1" -Body (.\diskUsage.ps1 | Out-String) -ErrorA ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessag`

My goal is to run the command remotely to many computers, and only get email notifications when the disk usage is above a threshold. My script currently returns nothing if the disk space check is OK, and this is my expected behaviour. I need `Send-MailMessage`, on the command itself, to simply not run if there is nothing to put in the body, without an error appearing in the console that the body is empty.

Comment: Wait, why not just do if(.\diskUsage.ps1 | Out-String) { ... } ? Am I missing something?

Comment: You could use splatting if you like e.g. https://ramblingcookiemonster.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/powershell-splatting-build-parameters-dynamically/

Comment: @JacobColvin I think I'm missing something... What would the `if()` do with the output, would it spit it out to a variable that I can then pass to `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: @ZiggZagg I checked out that blog post, but I don't think that fits in. I want `Send-MailMessage` to not run / not throw an error if the body is empty

Comment: @CanadianLuke Uhhh... No. You'd evaluate the condition. If empty, don't send, else send. The variable doesn't change. You should take like a codecademy course or something, no offense.

Comment: @JacobColvin No offense taken! I know very well that I'm a new Powershell Scripter, and I'm quite literally taking working examples on the Internet, and trying to adapt it for my own purposes.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Ok, well this is pretty basic programming. I'd recommend you just learn the basics with javascript or something a bit more popular. Because just by learning some basic operations you could go a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If specified, the body parameter is going to be verified for not being null or empty. Here is the body part from the open source version of PowerShell:

```
/// <summary>
/// Specifies the body (content) of the message
/// </summary>
[Parameter(Position = 2)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
public String Body
{
    get { return _body; }
    set
    {
        _body = value;
    }
}
private String _body;
```

Notice that if no `Body` is assigned the default value is going to be used which is not defined but rather an implementation detail and in this example null ([Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1)). Therefore not specifying the `Body` is what you would like to todo.
To ensure clean code you can use PowerShells `splatting` features or alternativly use simple branching using if statements.

### Simple If

```
$diskUsage = (.\diskUsage.ps1 | Out-String)

If ($diskUsage){
    # Disk usage was set
    Send-MailMessage -From "powershell@example.com" -To "tech@example.com" -Subject "Disk usage on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)" -SmtpServer "192.168.0.1" -Body $diskUsage -ErrorAction Continue
} Else {
    # Disk usage was not set notice that -body is omitted which is different from setting it to null or empty
    Send-MailMessage -From "powershell@example.com" -To "tech@example.com" -Subject "Disk usage on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)" -SmtpServer "192.168.0.1" -ErrorAction Continue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, emails are usuallly UTF8 to set the encoding of the body to `UTF8` by using `-Encoding UTF8`

If you are trying to capture the output of `diskUsage.ps1` it probably won't return a string like you think.

You can test it by running:

```
$output = & C:\path\to\diskUsage.ps1 | Out-String
if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($output)) { echo 'no string is being returned' } else { echo 'String returned' }
```

If it says `no string is being returned`, then you should rethink this command into a  script.

e.g. put the `diskUsage.ps1` and this `Send-MailMessage` command into one script.

Comment: Calling `IsNullOrEmpty()` is unnecessary since null or empty strings are false in PowerShell. For the negative test, `-not $output` Is sufficient and more idiomatically PowerShell.